# MongoDB where clause update

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection named 'profiles_bak' .i'd like to update the every document in the 'profiles_bak'.for a single condition the below mention code is working fine

```
 db.profiles_bak.update(
  {$where : "this.value1 > this.value2"},
  {$set : {"Gender": "male" }},false,true)
```

but i have to update based on multiple condition also i have mention my code what i have used so far or else any other approach how i can achieved this.

```
db.profiles_bak.update( { $and: [
    {query: { $where : "this.value1 > this.value2" },
    update: { $set : {"Gender": "male" }},false,true},
 {query: { $where : "this.value1 < this.value2" },
    update: { $set : {"Gender": "female" }},false,true}
 ]})
```

Comment: What should happen when value1 == value2?

Comment: nothing ..their is no case like that ..always value 1 either greater or less than value 2 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. Whilst you can construct an expression with JavaScript evaluation it cannot "alter" the the chosen result in the "update" block of the statement. Query logic is separated from the update statement block, and that statement block can only do exactly a singular operation based on the query conditions met.

These are "two" update statements. Use the [Bulk Operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) to make it more efficient:

```js
var bulk = db.profiles_bak.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

bulk.find({ "$where": "this.value1 > this.value2" }).update({
    "$set": { "Gender": "male" }
});
bulk.find({ "$where": "this.value1 < this.value2" }).update({
    "$set": { "Gender": "female" }
});
bulk.execute();
```

At least that is one request to the server an one reponse.

The [.update()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/) in Bulk is always set to "multi".

Comment: Thanks a lot Blakes Seven its working fine for me..i really appreciate for that